# Convert HTML to plain text maintaining line breaks

Tags: html, email, line-breaks

I am looking for some code which can convert my html string to plain text but it can convert the line breaks of html with "\r\n" line breaks . I want to send the output in my mail. How can I achieve this? what option should I go Regex, HTMLAgilityPack or else?

Comment: Can you use PHP like stripTags()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the opposite of nl2br function?

```
function br2nl($string){
  $return=eregi_replace('<br[[:space:]]*/?'.'[[:space:]]*>',chr(13).chr(10),$string);
  return $return;
}
```

Comment: Is your answer PHP?